# How do I transfer files from Linux to Windows server via the command line?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

How do I transfer files from Linux to Windows server via the command line?

No WinSCP
No FileZilla
No other similar tools...

When trying to run this command:

```
scp /home/user/testsite.html 001108@192.168.100.74:/c/Q4
```

This error occurs:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.74 port 22: Connection refused  
lost connection
```

Comment: So basically no command line tools at all ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have said tools, or that you couldn't install said tools?

Answer (score 1):

If your Linux OS has SSH client installed, then it also has scp. scp is used to copy files between servers in a secure, encrypted way. It uses ssh for data transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security as ssh.

When trying to run this command:

```
scp /home/user/testsite.html 001108@192.168.100.74:/c/Q4
```

You got the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.74 port 22: Connection refused   
lost connection
```

SSH by default uses port 22. Most likely there is no SSH server running on the remote host, or on a different port number, or it's blocked by a firewall.

- ping the machine (to test connectivity).
- See if there is an ssh deamon running.
- Run the same command but add the `-vvv` option to get more verbose output.